# Как получить владельца чата через Telethon?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

Возможно ли узнать `id` владельца чата через *Telethon*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsAdmins
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantCreator
import typing

async def get_owner_id(
    chat_id: int  # id чата, в котором нужно получить владельца
) -> typing.Union[int, bool]:
    owner_id = False

    async for user in client.iter_participants(
        chat_id, filter=ChannelParticipantsAdmins
    ):
        if isinstance(getattr(user, 'participant', None),
                      ChannelParticipantCreator
        ):
            return user.participant.user_id

    return owner_id
```